# How to do custom row numbering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, ranking, row-number

I have some data as follows:

```
[Row Number]
NULL
NULL
NULL
1
2
1
1
2
3
4
NULL
NULL
1
```

Assuming the data is already ordered in the way I want it, is it possible to assign new row numbers as follows?

```
[Row Number] [New Row Number]
NULL          1
NULL          2
NULL          3
1             4
2             4
1             5
1             6
2             6
3             6
4             6
NULL          7
NULL          8
1             9
```

The logic that I want is the following:

The `[New Row Number]` column should increment only when the `[Row Number]` column is `NULL` or `1`. For those with `[Row Number]` greater than `1`, they can be thought of as duplicates of the last `1` before that number.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2016?

Following the comments, I have also included the columns which I have ordered my data on below:

```
[PN] [CN] [Row Number] [New Row Number]
NULL 1    NULL         1
NULL 2    NULL         2
NULL 3    NULL         3
NULL 11   NULL         4
NULL 12   NULL         5
1    4    1            6
1    5    2            6
2    6    1            7
3    7    1            8
3    8    2            8
3    9    3            8
3    10   4            8
4    13   1            9
```

I have ordered my data on `[PN]` then `[CN]` then `[Row Number]`.

Just to rephrase my problem in another way, I want a row numbering system that considers each `NULL` value in the `PN` column as a distinct value and so the row number should increment. However, it should not increment when the `[PN]` is the same. `[CN]` is a unique identifier for each row i.e. no two rows have the same `[CN]`. Moreover, if `[PN]` is `NULL`, then `[Row Number]` would be `NULL`.

I did not think the positioning of the NULLs would matter previously, so my apologies for that!

Comment: With the data you've given us, your expected results are *impossible*; there is nothing to denote the order of the data in your single column. Why, for example, is `2` after `1` but before `1` and after `NULL` but before `NULL` (the ambiguity here is intentional to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: "Assuming the data is already ordered " - the only way to assume such a thing is to assume another column from which to draw the order of the data. In a relational database, data isn't ordered inherently.  You can read more about it in my blog post from a few years ago called [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: *"Assuming the data is already ordered in the way I want it"* This means you have an deterministic `ORDER BY` in  your query returning the data; you should share what that `ORDER BY` is, and include the columns in your sample data.

Comment: It is, yes (though not with `ROW_NUMBER`), but my point remains about it's not possible with your data as it stands.

Comment: Yes, this is a simple aggregated sum: `select *,sum(case when ISNULL(data, 1) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by inheritsort) from yourtable`

Comment: @ThomA Hi! Thank you for your comment! My apologies for not including more detailed data. I have now edited my post. Does the extra information help?

Comment: @siggemannen omg, that's it. I was so fixated on functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK` that I had not even thought of summing. If you could write this as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it so that the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by a simple window aggregated summary:

```sql
DECLARE @data TABLE (data  int, expected int, inheritsort int)

INSERT INTO @data
SELECT  col1 AS data
,   col2 AS expected
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@trancount) AS inheritSort
FROM
(
    VALUES  (NULL, 1)
    ,   (NULL, 2)
    ,   (NULL, 3)
    ,   (1, 4)
    ,   (2, 4)
    ,   (1, 5)
    ,   (1, 6)
    ,   (2, 6)
    ,   (3, 6)
    ,   (4, 6)
    ,   (NULL, 7)
    ,   (NULL, 8)
    ,   (1, 9)
) t (col1,col2)


SELECT  *
,   SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(data, 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY inheritsort ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rowIdActual
FROM    @data
```

Outputs:

| data | expected | inheritsort | rowIdActual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NULL | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| NULL | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | 6 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 | 10 | 6 |
| NULL | 7 | 11 | 7 |
| NULL | 8 | 12 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 | 13 | 9 |

Comment: IT'll likely be more perfomant to define in the window that you want `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (which can be abbreviated to `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`), otherwise it defaults to `RANGE`.

Comment: Good call @ThomA, i keep forgetting that perf. optimization, edited it in